# Increasing Google cloud snapshot frequency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

just wondering if there is a way (either with third party solutions or native) to take snapshots of persistent disks every 10 minutes (or less).

At the moment, the automatic schedule only allows hourly backups.

[image]

thanks 
Anil.

Comment: No - you have the problem that a snapshot must complete before the next snapshot can start. Keep in mind that you will have a sizable bill creating snaphots one after the other to pay for the storage space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [a workaround](https://github.com/cizara/google-cloud-auto-snapshot) that uses a couple of bash scripts to make a snapshot of a subset of persistent disks in a project with a manually specified period.

The subset is defined by filtering disks with a label `backup=yes`. To apply this label to a disk, run this command:

```
gcloud beta compute disks add-labels <DISK-NAME> --zone=<DISK-LOCATION> --labels=backup=yes
```

Step by step, this is how it worked for me:

1. Get the scripts: `git clone https://github.com/cizara/google-cloud-auto-snapshot.git`
2. `cd` into the directory where the code is
3. Change lines 8 and 11 of `entrypoint.sh`, writing the period in seconds (e.g. `SLEEP=600`, for 10 minutes) and the path to the other script, for instance `./google-cloud-auto-snapshot.sh`.
4. Give execution permissions with `chmod +x entrypoint.sh google-cloud-auto-snapshot.sh` to both scripts and run `entrypoint.sh`.

Note that performing this operation with short periods and too many/large disks can be very expensive.